# (react-three-fiber) Update position of mesh relative to box

Tags: react-three-fiber

This is a simple moving box. What I am trying to do is to have the mesh position anchored to the boxBufferGeometry as it loops its animation, but it appears that the mesh is just falling into infinity after initial render.

packages used:

```
"@react-three/cannon": "^6.5.2",
"@react-three/drei": "^9.77.3",
"@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.3",
"react-spring": "^9.7.1",
"three": "^0.153.0"
```

code:

```
const Pusher = (props: BoxProps) => {
  const boxRef = useRef<Mesh<BufferGeometry, Material | Material[]>>(null);
  const meshRef = useRef<Mesh<BufferGeometry, Material | Material[]>>(null);
  let direction = 1;
  let position = -5;

  useBox(() => ({
    mass: 1,
    args: [9.9, 1, 1],
    position: meshRef.current ? meshRef.current.position.toArray() : [0, 0, -5],
    collisionFilterGroup: 1,
    collisionFilterMask: 1,
    ...props
  }));

  useFrame(() => {
    position += 0.01 * direction;
    if (boxRef.current) {
      boxRef.current.position.set(0, 0, position);
    }
    if (position > -4 || position < -6) {
      direction *= -1;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (boxRef.current && meshRef.current) {
      const [x, y, z] = boxRef.current.position.toArray();
      meshRef.current.position.set(x, y, z);
    }
  }, [boxRef, meshRef]);

  return (
    <mesh ref={boxRef}>
      <boxBufferGeometry args={[10, 2.1, 6]} />
      <meshPhongMaterial color="#ff0000" opacity={0.3} transparent />
      {/* <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" color={import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_COLOR} /> */}
    </mesh>
  );
};
```